# Наилучший способ добавлять картинки к документации на код

Tags: документация, doxygen

Самый правильный способ добавить документацию к коду - разместить её рядом с кодом. В этом случае, если меняется код, то с высокой вероятностью разработчик не забудет обновить и документацию. А если документация лежит где-то отдельно, то её часто забывают актуализировать.

Для реализации этой концепции был придуман doxygen и другие подобные системы, при использовании которых документация представляет собой человекочитаемые комментарии прямо в коде.

Но к сожалению doxygen не позволяет вставлять в документацию картинки. По крайней мере простым способом. А мне приходится часто реализовывать геометрические алгоритмы и одна картинка позволяет заменить сотню слов. А иногда без картинок вовсе не обойтись.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие способы снабдить вашу документацию на код картинками вы используете?

Comment: я для документации java проекта использую Ascii Doctor и плагин к нему  Аscii Doctor Diagram. но я делаю это в отдельном документе, а не в коде. по этому пишу в комментарий.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а Ascii Doctor не умеет вытаскивать javadoc-комментарии из кода?

Comment: Андрей, вы нашли какое-нибудь решение? Если да, то поделитесь, пожалуйста. Будущим читателям будет полезно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin насколько я знаю нет. но можно писать javadoc комментарии используя формат AsciiDoctor https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, посмотрю. А из ваших проектов, документированных в AsciiDoc, есть что-нибудь в открытом доступе? Тоже с интересом посмотрел бы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin к сожалению все проекты закрытые.

Comment: посмотрите описание команды \image в документации к doxygen

Answer (score 0):

Добавь ссылку на картинку. Я для документации использую markdown, потом преобразовываю его в pdf через `mdpdf` (npm-пакет, очень прост в использовании и установке). В pdf `<image stc='...' />` превращается в изображение. Возможно, в doxygen есть что-то похожее (см. комментарий @Uhv).
Но `<image stc='...' />` можно добавить непосредственно в комментарии к функции/классу.